# What is the model architecture used in spacy's token vectors (english)

Tags: python, spacy

I am most likely missing something obvious, but what approach/model was used to train the Token vectors in spacy's english medium model?  Was it word2vec?  A deep learning architecture?  Just curious on what was used to estimate those embeddings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The English vectors are GloVe Common Crawl vectors. Most other languages have custom fastText vectors from OSCAR Common Crawl + Wikipedia. These sources should be included in the model metadata, but it looks like the vector information has been accidentally left out in the `3.0.0` model releases.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!  Might ask ask, where is that documented?  I have been searching but perhaps just totally missing it.

Comment: It's documented for the most recent v2 models here: https://v2.spacy.io/models in the description + sources. The v3 model info will be updated the next time a new set of models is released. None of the vectors changed between v2.3.x and v3.0, but a few languages were added (Macedonian: custom fastText, Russian: Navec).